# What is the data type returned for an IF function (SharePoint Calculated Column)?

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, type-conversion, calculated-columns

I have a rather long calculated column which uses the drop-downs of two other columns to return a 'score' based on their values.

A section of it looks like this:

```
IF(AND([Current Impact]="High",[Current Probability]="Low"),17)
```

This would return the value 17 if the impact is high and the probability is low in those other columns.

This seems to return the 17 as a string rather than a number because sorting on my calculated column (score) from high to low produces a result sorted on the first digit e.g. 5, 4, 32, 2, 18

I have a workaround to this - I enclose the whole formula in a (an?) `=value()` function.

However, I'm curious as to why the IF function returns the string data types instead of a number?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in the column settings you could specify  what data type returned from the calculated formula:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I have selected "Number" as the data type returned in my column - but it still sorts as if it were a string...